# File name via tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile guaranteed to be unique in multi-threading in Azure Function Python App hosted in Linux and Windows

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

Is the file name, `fp.name`, in the code below guaranteed to be unique, even in a concurrent multi-thread environment, running in Azure Function app hosted in both Linux and Windows?

```
tempFilePath = tempfile.gettempdir()
fp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.csv')
fp.write(b'Hello world!')
filesDirListInTemp = listdir(tempFilePath)
```

http://www.pererikstrandberg.se/blog/index.cgi?page=PythonTemporaryFiles

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?source=recommendations&tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-configuration#temporary-files